# Cannot Pick a video from gallery and set to a video html tag - windows phone silverlight 8.1

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

I picked a video from gallery using FileOpenPicker

and took his path which is something like this path=C:\Data\Users\Public\Pictures\Camera Roll\WP_20150410_001.mp4

then I set up this path to my video source tag but instead of getting my video, I am displaying a message "Aborted".

If I replace my path with this string "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" I got the video.

What is wrong with my solution? How to fix it? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain your scenario and provide more details? Where are you trying to run this? Is this on phone or ripple?

Comment: it is a windows phone 8.1 and I am running my app on it. My app is a cordova hybrid app made with html javascript and c#